# WSO2 API Manager - Unprotected resource at API Product level

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to create an unprotected API in an API Product but it always asks for credentials.

I realized that, when you add a resource in API Product, this resource inherits source API configuration, so if I disable security to specific path, it is supposed to replicate this configuration to resource at API Product level because security config is disabled in API Product.

For example, let's suppose there is an API called /user/add and it is unprotected. Then I add this api to API product with API key security. When I call API /user/add, without any security header it works property but when I call it through api product /apiproduct/user/add, access is denied.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question with examples ?

Comment: Hello, I updated question with an example. Please let me know if is it clearer now. Thanks!

Comment: I just checked this and was able to observe the same behaviour. This happens only in API key security type for API product. Seems like a bug. Please open a git issue in https://github.com/wso2/product-apim

Comment: Yeah, actually I did it few days ago: https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/9661